# add a event DocumentCompleted to a WebBrowser in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events

I want to add a event DocumentCompleted to my control WebBrowser. This is my code. but it doesn't work.

```html
        <asp:Button id="Button_Auth" Text="Authentification" OnClick="Authentification_Click"  runat="server"/>
        <asp:label id="Messages" runat="server"/>
```

```
     public void Authentification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = "https://www.google.fr";
        runBrowserThread(input );

        Messages.Text = "ok";
    }



    private void runBrowserThread(String url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() => {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(browser_DocumentCompleted);
            br.Navigate(url,true);
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    public void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;
        Messages.Text = e.Url.ToString();

    }
```

What I want is open a new page webBrowser and everytime when the page(in the case `https://www.google.fr` )finishes loading, For example, User enter a key word and search it. when the page of result finishes loading, I will get back the url of result `https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=keyword` and display it in my label Messages.

I don't know why my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the event is right fully wierd to your event handler.

Is it a asp.net application or is it winforms application or wpf application? In asp.net application this event is not available. If asp.net try JavaScript

Comment: It's an asp .net web application. You means that event DocumentCompleted can be only used in winforms application?OK...maybe that's right. By the way,can you give an example of JavaScript's code for this. Thanks.

Comment: But you can't add JavaScript to somebody else's page in this case Google.fr, you can design your own page, and then add JavaScript which will get triggered on document load completed event. In jquery it is easy to do since there is pre-built event for this. But for the scenario you are mentioning looks like you need to capture the result URL of Google search, I think you have to go in winforms direction. Even your code which opens a web browser control in a threaded manner will only work in a desktop application but not in asp.net.

Comment: Ok I see that. That means we can't get the URL in others 
domain name with Javascript. And if we wan to do that with c#, that must be a winform application. Can we have others ways, in a asp .net web applicaion, to get a URL in a web brower even if not in my domain name. Thanks.

Comment: I think if your own page runs, and in that page your javascript code runs, i think you can read window.location which is basically the url. But it won't serve your purpose exactly, probably you need to modify your requirement and take a different approach.

Comment: OK... I think I will take another approach. anyway thanks for your help.